# How can I reduce generic <? extends Type> to Type in Java. Code valid at run time but fail to compile

Tags: java, generics

I use Spring Boot .yaml for configs and made hierarchy of config classes so other application can define additional properties. Config itself has hierarchical structure.

To keep it open for extension I use `<? extends Type>` generic declaration.

That causes problem when I try to reduce `<? extends Type>` to `Type`.

Following fully working minimal example demonstrate issue (in `getSubConfs` method):

```
public static class Conf<S> {
    public String name;
    public Map<String, S> subConfs;
}

public static class SubConf {
    public String name;
    public Conf<? extends SubConf> conf;
}

public static Map<String, SubConf> getSubConfs(SubConf subconf) {
    // incompatible types: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,capture#1 of ? extends App.SubConf>
    // cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,App.SubConf>
    return subconf.conf.subConfs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Conf<SubConf> cfg = new Conf<>();
    cfg.name = "cfg";
    SubConf subcfg = new SubConf();
    subcfg.name = "subcfg";
    subcfg.conf = cfg;
    cfg.subConfs = new HashMap<>();
    cfg.subConfs.put(subcfg.name, subcfg);

    Map<String, SubConf> subConfs = getSubConfs(subcfg);
    System.out.println(subConfs.get("subcfg").name);
}
```

On `getSubConfs(subcfg)` call I expect to obtain `Map<String, SubConf>` because I do not care of further possible specialization of `subcfg`, I have needs to access only to common properties.

Valid code is:

```
public static Map<String, ? extends SubConf> getSubConfs2(SubConf subconf) {
    Conf<? extends SubConf> cfg = subconf.conf;
    return cfg.subConfs;
}
```

but I can't see why I should have `? extends SubConf` in API if in runtime there is no type problems.

**UPDATE** With function:

```
public static Map<String, SubConf> getSubConfs(SubConf subconf) {
    Conf<? extends SubConf> cfg = subconf.conf;
    return (Map<String, SubConf>) cfg.subConfs;
}
```

shows that there is not any runtime problems with code, even if with `-XLint:unchecked`:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
    return (Map<String, SubConf>) cfg.subConfs;
required: Map<String,SubConf>
found:    Map<String,CAP#1>
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
  CAP#1 extends SubConf from capture of ? extends SubConf
```

Of course I can decorate function with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: Assume you have a `Map<string, SubSubConf>` and a `Map<string, SubConf>`. Can you insert a `SubConf` into the former? The latter? What about `SubSubConf`? If you've thought through that the reason should be pretty clear.

Comment: **@MattiaDinosaur** For `<? extends Type>` compiler reduces type to `Type` and I have valid usage of this type. The problem only with type inference, not at runtime.

Comment: Generics only exists at compile time. That doesn't mean it's safe to ignore it. The warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: **@shmosel** Can you be more specific regarding provided example? Because I can write such pathetic statement myself to each generic related question ))

Comment: @gavenkoa Try to answer the questions from my first comment and you have your example. I'm assuming English isn't your first language, so you might not be aware, but "pathetic" is an unnecessarily offensive and aggressive word to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your method `getSubConfs()` is that `SubConf.conf` is of type `Conf<? extends SubConf>`. Then `Conf.subConfs` is of type `Map<String, ? extends SubConf>`, but this `Map` is not compatible with `Map<String, SubConf>` you want to get.

The reason of incompatibility is that there is no way to tell what implementation of SubConf is in `Map<String, ? extends SubConf>`. You can read SubConf values out of it, but you cannot add anything into it (you could end up mixing different implementations). The `Map<String, SubConf>` is clear about its type and you can safely read and add items to it:

```
// Assuming SubConf2 and SubConf3 both extend SubConf ...
HashMap<String, SubConf2> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, ? extends SubConf> subconfMap = map;
// This doesn't work, because then you could call map.get("key") 
// and get SubConf3 which is not compatible with the declared SubConf2
subconfMap.put("key", new SubConf3());

// The problem cannot happen with with Map<String, SubConf>, because
// the following statement causes compile time error:
Map<String, SubConf> subconfMap = new HashMap<String, SubConf2>();
```